# Trying to get displayed days down to physical days rather then days with a point at the end

Tags: c#, .net

At work I made a countdown timer, but when it displays the days until open it display it as 67.556644254432 in that type of format.  I am looking at getting it so the . days are not in there.  This is the code I have so far.

```
DateTime projectedOpening = DateTime.Parse("5/28/2019");
        TimeSpan daysLeft = projectedOpening.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

        resultLabel.Text = string.Format("The Projected opening of Med/Surg is {0} There is {1:00} days before that day is here",
            projectedOpening.ToShortDateString(), daysLeft.TotalDays.ToString());
```

Comment: C#, not C... please check your tags

Comment: So you are getting `double` value, but you want it truncated..do you know how to truncate/round down a `double`?

Comment: Thank you Eugene how do I mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: It's not an answer but a comment, so you don't :)